# Intellij IDEA Plugin to read and print the contents in a IDE editor in console

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, console, printf, editor

I am new to Intellij Idea plugin development using gradle! I am hoping to develop a simple plugin to read the contents of java class and print it in the console(Toolwindow) in  a live manner(i.e when I type a new word in the java class it should print the work in the console even if the class is saved or not)

Currently I am refering to the Intellij plugin architecture and components in https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_components.html. I came across concepts such as editor panes and all But I have no idea how to read the contents in IDE editor(current java file)! How can I do it?

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console - look at the Tail functionality

Comment: @Meo thanx but I want to write my own plugin

Comment: how to read the editor: `PlatformDataKeys.EDITOR.getData(anActionEvent.getDataContext()).getDocument().getText()`

Comment: @meo Can you give an link so that I can get an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the raw text of an editor window:

```
Editor editor = anActionEvent.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);
editor.getDocument().getText();
```

If you want to get some structure from the contents of the editor window, you can use the `PsiFile` API:

```
PsiFile psi = anActionEvent.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
```

The `PsiFile` API lets you walk through a file in whatever language(s) make sense. For example, for Java files there is a `PsiJavaFile` interface that knows about Java specific features like package name, imports, etc.

http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi_files.html

Lastly, to print a message you can try normal `System.out.print()` or you can use the `ConsoleView` class to work with the IntelliJ console tool views:

```
TextConsoleBuilderFactory.getInstance()
                         .createBuilder(anActionEvent.getProject())
                         .getConsole()
                         .print("Hello", ConsoleViewContentType.NORMAL_OUTPUT);
```

One note: All of the above code assumes you're working with an `ActionEvent`. You might want to check out the `TypedActionHandler` interface to get notified when the editor text changes:

http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/editor_basics/editor_events.html#handling-keystrokes-in-the-editor